# How to load file on the worker with distributed dask scheduler?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I setup manually a dask-scheduler and a dask-worker. They see each other regarding the logs.

I have big file located on the same machine than the scheduler (where my jupyter notebook runs too).

But when I load my file with `dd.read_csv`, I have the common `No such a file or directory` error.

I understand the data locality problem but how can I send my file to the cluster transparently ?

I can't find (or understand ?) in [documentation resource](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html) or [data locality](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locality.html#user-control)

Comment: Is a shared file-system or `scp` an option?

Comment: Yes. It's a solution. But I wonder if there was something implemented in dask.

Comment: No. Dask can copy files to worker nodes from the client, but it is not meant for large data files.

Comment: OK ! Thanks for the clarification. I will not spend time searching something which does not exist :)

Answer (score 2):

You can load the file in your notebook as a Python object (like a pandas dataframe or numpy array) and then scatter it out to the workers.  You can also look at the `Client.upload_file` method.